# Is it possible to control the datefmt of the Celery task logs?

Tags: python, logging, celery

With normal python loggers you might configure the format string and date format like so:

```
{                                                                                                     
    'format': '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)d [%(process)d] %(levelname)s [%(name)s] %(message)s',                       
    'datefmt': %d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S'                                                                              
}
```

But I am completely unable to find any way to pass a `datefmt` to the Celery task logger. It seems like such a basic bit of functionality that I'm surprised if it is impossible.

The closest I got was by following the technique layed out in [this article](https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/11/06/celery-task-logger-format/). The gist of it is to use the `after_setup_task_logger` signal to customize the logger handler to pass a custom `TaskFormatter`. But the trick is that while `TaskFormatter` let's you pass a format string, it doesn't seem to have any provision to allow you to pass a `datefmt`.

This seems to be confirmed by [this open issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5364) on the Celery github.

So is there something obvious I'm missing? A trick that can be done without having to wait for celery to handle the above issue? Is it really impossible?

Comment: I should point out that, while I'm open to upgrading celery if that will solve the issue, I am using version 4.2.1, and would prefer a solution which does not require an upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to set the datefmt after the task formatter has been created by setting the datefmt attribute. The `__init__` of the [Formatter](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L579) is doing just that.

```
tf = TaskFormatter('%(asctime)s.%(msecs)d [%(process)d] %(levelname)s [%(name)s] %(message)s')
tf.datefmt = '%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S' 
handler.setFormatter(tf)
```